# Evaluate $\:\int _{-\infty }^{+\infty \:}\frac{x\sin (\pi x)}{x^2+2x+5}\,dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)=\frac{ze^{i\pi z}}{z^2+2z+5}$ whose poles are:

$z=-1\pm 2i$

$\gamma =\gamma 1\:∪\:\gamma 2$

$γ1\left(t\right)\:=\:t,\:\:\:\:t\:∈\:[−R,\:R]$

$\gamma 2\left(t\right)\:=\:Reit,\:\:\:t\:∈\:[0,\:\pi ]$

$\int _{\gamma }f(z)\,dz=2i\pi \operatorname{Res}(f,\:-1+2i)$

$\operatorname{Res}\left(f,\:-1+2i\right)=\lim _{z\to -1+2i}\left(\frac{ze^{i\pi z}}{z+1+2i}\right)$

$=-\frac{(-1+2i)e^{-2\pi }}{4i}$

$\int _{\gamma 1}^{ }f\left(z\right)dz+\int _{\gamma 2}^{\:}f(z)\,dz=-\frac{\pi \left(-1+2i\right)e^{-2\pi }}{2}$

$\int _{\gamma 2}^{\:}f(z)\,dz$ vanishes as $R\rightarrow +\infty $

$\int _{-R}^R\frac{t\left(\cos\left(\pi t\right)+i\sin\left(\pi t\right)\right)}{t^2+2t+5}\,dt=\frac{\pi \:e^{-2\pi \:}}{2}-i\pi e^{-2\pi }$

Equating real and imaginary parts, we finally have:

$\:\int _{-\infty }^{+\infty \:}\frac{x\sin\left(\pi x\right)}{x^2+2x+5}\,dx$ $=-\pi e^{-2\pi }$

Please tell me if I made a mistake, also can anyone demonstrate why the integral on the half circle vanishes? That's the part I don't understand perfectly.

Comment: The result is correct.